# MongoDB find in dictionary by value when property name change

Tags: mongodb

My documents are:

```
{
  animals: {
    cats: [ { weight: 3 }, { weight: 5} ],
    cows: [ { weight: 15 }, { weight: 21}, { weight: 14} ]
  }
}
{
  animals: {
    dogs: [ { weight: 6 }, { weight: 7} ],
    chickens: [ { weight: 2}, { weight: 3}, { weight: 2.5} ],
    mouses: [ { weight: 0.5 } ]
  }
}
```

I want a query matching every document containing an animal with a weight lower than 1.
My issue is that animals' names change from document to document, I do not know how to deal with that. I expect something along the way of `collection.find({ "animals.*.weight": { $lt: 1 } })` but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      animals: {
        "$objectToArray": "$animals"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "animals.v.weight": {
        $lt: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BktGE73BlVU).

The first stage converts the animals object to an array. After the stage, the documents have the following form:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "animals": [
      {
        "k": "cats",
        "v": [
          {
            "weight": 3
          },
          {
            "weight": 5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "k": "cows",
        "v": [
          {
            "weight": 15
          },
          {
            "weight": 21
          },
          {
            "weight": 14
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

The second stage filters the documents by the criteria you specify. If the query is conducted repeatedly, it might be worth adjusting your data schema to support it.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much <3